# The word "decorum" as a synonym for "fairness"?

Tags: synonyms

Would 'decorum' work as a synonym for 'fairness'? The context is "The Decorum of Justice" which is the title for one of my spoken word poems. "The Fairness of Justice" just doesn't have the same feel to it.

If this word choice doesn't work, are there synonyms of fairness that would work just as well?

Comment: Not exactly fairness or decorum : "solemnity" or "etiquette".

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a synonym for "fairness".  It means "behaviour in keeping with good taste and propriety."  (oxford) That is "the right and respectable thing to do".

I think this is rather an XY problem, since Justice is a synonym for "fairness", so I don't think you should use a word that means "fairness" at all.   "The Decorum of Justice" works fine as a title about Justice being the right thing to do

Comment: I'd think of the 'decorum of justice' as wearing wigs, saying 'All rise!', 'My Lord', 'Your Honour', 'My learned friend', etc, and nothing to do with the fairness of a court or legal system. Indeed, that 'decorum' can co-exist with the most wicked kinds of injustice.